# django 1.3 server error

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

I am using django version 1.3. Python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 gives the following error.

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by < bound method Command.inner_run of < django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x20eb110>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 88, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 36, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tastypie.utils import now

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/utils/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tastypie.utils.dict import dict_strip_unicode_keys

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/utils/dict.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import smart_bytes
ImportError: cannot import name smart_bytes
```

Answer (score 6):

Its working fine with [django 1.4.2+](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/2.4.7/changelog.html), I was using django1.4 then upgraded it

```
pip install django==1.4.5 --upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

**Django 1.3** had the issues of `smart_bytes`, and from your *traceback* it shows the same error, its been resolved in **Django 1.4**, Try upgrading **Django** to the latest version of **1.5**.

Comment: Yes django 1.3 with django-tastypie version 0.10.0 gives this error. Either i upgrade django or degrade django-tastypie to 0.9.11 worked.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/encoding.py#L149

Also, always check the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/) before upgrading your Django.

Update:

Sorry about that, wow, what a brainfart ;).

I don't know the full history of that function, but looking at django.utils.encoding on Github.. tagged 1.3.7; this file does not contain the function that Tastypie is attempting to import. https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.7/django/utils/encoding.py

If you cannot upgrade Django, you'll need to patch your Tastypie.utils.dict file to work with what you have.

Comment: I would have voted this answer down only if i had that much reputation. Please see the traceback carefully.